# For Loop finishes before Mongoose FindOne does

Tags: node.js

I've searched around for a while now (off and on for a couple weeks) on how to solve this problem.  ATM I have it working but its hard coded and looong.  I have an inventory system that needs to loop through a list of UPC's and then look up each UPC via Mongoose's FindOne.  I am not sure if the res.render line is being called and executed before the For Loop finishes or if the FindOne is not finishing in time.  The only thing I get displayed in "order" is the contact information which is done before I enter the loop.

Most to all of my experience is not with node.js so that is why my code looks the way it does.

Here is the code that I have:

```
app.post('/want', (req, res) => {
var order = "Contact:"+req.body.Contact+"\n";

for(var i = 100; i < 800; i++){
    if(req.body[i] > 0){
        Extract.findOne({upc: i}, function(err, extract){
            order += extract.name + '/' + extract.type + ' - ' + req.body[i];
        });
    }
}

res.render("order.hbs",{
    pageTitle: "Order Confirmation",
    order: order
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What you should do

Mongoose supports ranges in its queries. You really, really should use a range, e.g

```
Extract.find({ upc: { $gt: 100, $lt: 800 } }).then((extracts) => {
    extracts.forEach((extract, i) => {
        let realIndex = i + 100;
        order += extract.name + '/' + extract.type + ' - ' + req.body[realIndex];
    });

    res.render("order.hbs",{
        pageTitle: "Order Confirmation",
        order: order
    });

}).catch(() => res.sendStatus(500));
```

---

### What you shouldn't do

As you may know, `findOne` is an asynchronous function (that's why it takes a callback).

In order to have the correct answer you must *wait* until all your asynchronous calls are done. One way to do it is to use promises.

e.g

```
app.post('/want', (req, res) => {
    let order = "Contact:"+req.body.Contact+"\n";
    const promises = [];

    for(let i = 100; i < 800; i++){
        if (req.body[i] > 0){
            promises.push(() => return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                Extract.findOne({upc: i})
                    .then(extract => resolve({ extract: extract, index: i}))
                    .catch(reject);
            });
        }
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then((values) => {
        values.forEach((value) => {
            order += value.extract.name + '/' + value.extract.type + ' - ' + req.body[value.index];
        }):

        res.render("order.hbs",{
            pageTitle: "Order Confirmation",
            order: order
        });
   }).catch(() => res.sendStatus(500));
});
```

---

What I've done here may appear as tricky at first so let me break it down here:

- I'm defining a new const array (its type will not change from array to something else).
- For each loop I'll push a new promise into this array.
- When all promises are done (that's what `Promise.all` does), I'll do your string concatenation and then return.

---

I could push `Extract.findOne()` into the array ; but since you need the index in your string concatenation, I'm actually forced to create a new promise that will return an object with two values: the `extract` and the `index`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an experienced node.js developer, but if I were you, I will try the Promise.all to execute the promise and get the result array or send the UPC array to mongo, use aggregate in mongo to get the result.